# How to switch reactor framework to be completely synchronous?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, project-reactor, mockmvc

I have a big enterprise application that has async computations based on Reactor 3 framework. However, this project is principally based on synchronous calls, so REST controllers may have only 1 or 2 async methods among 10 sync ones. The problem is in the async methods. They don't return `Mono` or `Flux` from the controller, but instead they are using `subscribe()`. For example:

```
    @Operation(summary = "Summary")
    @PostMapping(path = "/path/full")
    public void compute(
            @RequestBody
            @Validated
            @JsonView
            DTO request
    ) throws Exception {
        service.compute(request).subscribe();
    }
```

How am I suppose to write integration test with `mvcMock` if I can't subscribe or block the emitter of `compute(request)` method? Is there a way to switch Reactor into a fully synchronous mode?

Comment: Is it necessary to use mockMvc? Why don't you use `reactor-test` to test your reactive controllers?

Comment: Because they are not reactive. They don't return reactive types.

Comment: I the example you gave I don't see what is stopping you to return a Mono<Void>. But anyway what do you want to mock here ?

Comment: I want this endpoint to run computation in the background meanwhile returning `200 SUCCESS` to the user. If I make it return `Mono<Void>`, I will need to use `MockMvc` for my other endpoints which are returning non-flux classes, and `WebTestClient` together. Which is not possible.

Comment: @Praytic It's not possible to the best of my knowledge, but I'd argue you *shouldn't* do this, as the moment you switch reactor to be synchronous, you're fundamentally changing its behaviour in a significant way, which would defeat the point of your tests. This sort of behaviour is one of the side-effects of using an "inner subscribe" fire-and-forget model unfortunately. I think the best you can do in this case is just check it returns a 200, and then create a separate unit test to mock the service, and check that the `compute(request).subscribe()` method is invoked.

Comment: How it would defeat the point of my tests if the only thing this method does is detaching a function from the thread?